# Using String Data With Shared Preferences

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, flutter-dependencies

I have a login page and I want to save my username data with shared preferences and use it in my app. How can I do that? I couldn't figure out how to use the shared preferences.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you haven't given in an honest try yet. From the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) it is written at the top:

```
// Obtain shared preferences.
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

// Save an String value to 'action' key.
await prefs.setString('action', 'Start');

// Try reading data from the 'action' key. If it doesn't exist, returns null.
final String? action = prefs.getString('action');
```